# how to dynamically create xml layout multiple times inside getview() method in android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, layout-xml

I have already created `xml-layout` file which contain `View` like comment box. I want to create dynamically layout (comment box) multiple times inside `getView()` method. How can i create it dynamically inside `getView()` method?

Here inside `getview()` method i have used code for dynamically generate particular `View` multiple times but it doesn't work. Please give me suggestion.

My adapter code link is below:

http://pastebin.com/aAYdPbn9

Comment: you cannot create xml layout from code ... but you can create Views from code ... anyway, question is unclear

Comment: I have one layout in xml file that is look like comment box.
I want to create this comment box multiple times dynamically.

Comment: real programmers do not use term: `it doesn't work` ...

Comment: Do you refer to Adapter's getView() or Fragments's getView()?

Comment: yes but i want to repeat one layout multiple times inside getview() method.

Comment: real programmers help each other instead of making unnecessary comments.

Comment: @Tardo `unnecessary comments` like yours? my wasn't unnecessary ... it was helpful ... he should edit the question and explain what "doesn't work" means to him ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three approaches for you. As discussed in the comments the title of your question is misleading, so this is what I assume:

- you have a list of cards you want to display
- each card may have a list of comments

So the underlying problem is, that you have a **two-dimensional data structure**, which you want to display using a **one-dimensional UI component**, in your case a ListView.

You can solve your problem by:

1. Using an ExpandableListView, where the cards are the parent and the comments are the child elements. See [1] for an example.
2. Flatten your data hierarchy. So you only have a list of items, where the cards are somehow treated as "headers" or "separators" for your comments. You need to overwrite [2], in that case your Adapter is capable of returning two different views. In the `getView()` method you then need to do something like:

   `if(list.get(position) instanceOf Card)
     return getCardView(...);
   else if(list.get(position) instanceOf Comment)
     return getCommentView(...);`
3. Render the comments dynamically into a container within the card view. So in your layout file for your card view use a ViewGroup, e.g. a LinearLayout and give it a unique id, like "llComments". Have a separated layout file for your comments. Then in your current code you can inflate this file and just add the returned view to the container (llComments). I think this is the solution you are looking for. So, in your code, do something like:

   `View commentConvertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_comment, ...);
   ViewGroup comments = (ViewGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llComments);
   comments.removeAllView;
   for(list.get(position).getComments()){
      //bind the data to commentConvertView
      comments.add(commentConvertView);
   }`

[1] http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview_concept
[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()

Comment: Thank u for giving answer. can u have any code link or demo?? I really want try this approach...

Comment: There are many tutorial out there which demonstrate the correct use of Adapters. If you may be emphasize a little further what you want to achieve, I can extend my answer with an example for your case. Otherwise, this blog shows one simple example http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.de

Comment: Can you please elaborate this thing ? if you understand my coding and what i want to do?